# Difference between GROUP_CONCAT() and CONCAT_WS()?

Tags: mysql

I have searched unsuccessfully for a satisfactory explanation on the difference between `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `CONCAT_WS()`.

Are they as closely related as I think they are?

What are the differences in usage, speed, etc. between these two functions?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is used when you want to have non-NULL values from different column rows in a single row. For this you need to have GROUP BY to work.

`CONCAT_WS` is to join two or more strings.

Example,

`GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) ORDER BY id ASC SEPARATOR ',');`

Outputs something like,

`John Doe,Blah Blah,Tom Cruise,Lorem Ipsum`

here space between the name is because of `CONCAT_WS`,
while whole result in one row is because of `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Also, if you want to use a separator with `GROUP_CONCAT`, you can use the `SEPARATOR` statement like this:  `GROUP_CONCAT(lastname SEPARATOR '-')`

Comment: `CONCAT_WS()` can actually join an arbitrary number of values, not just two. The PHP equivalent is `implode()`.

Answer (score 11):

Pictorial difference:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php
[image]

**GROUP_CONCAT** below

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php
[image]